# Apresentar informações mais importantes de um arquivo JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Como faço para apresentar apenas algumas das informações mais importantes de uma lista como do exemplo a seguir?

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "DRF - Delegacia de Roubos e Furtos",
    "endereco": "Praca Maua, 5 - Centro",
    "tel":"2233-2701",
    "long":"-22.896893,0",
    "lat":"-43.181976"
},
```

Não importa se utilizar AngularJS, JSON, JavaScript. Eu apenas gostaria de saber como faço para puxar apenas uma informação para evitar repetições. Por exemplo: como apresentar em um local apenas o nome, endereço e telefone do local para os usuários verem?

Comment: Ok, mas como puxa as informações atualmente? Como podemos ajudar a melhorar seu código atual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua pergunta menciona explicitamente 'apresentação'. Assim sendo, a resposta é fácil - exiba apenas os campos que necessitar. Exemplo:

```js
function SampleController($scope) {
  $scope.dados = [
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "title": "DRF - Delegacia de Roubos e Furtos",
      "endereco": "Praca Maua, 5 - Centro",
      "tel":"2233-2701",
      "long":"-22.896893,0",
      "lat":"-43.181976"
    }];
}
```

```html
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="SampleController">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>
            ID
          </th>
          <th>
            Local
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat='i in dados'>
          <td>{{i.id}}</td>
          <td>{{i.title}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ao executar este código, perceba que apenas duas propriedades são exibidas.

Answer (score 2):

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>CDN ANGULAR JS</head>
<body ng-controller="Crtl">
{{user.id}}
</body>
</html>


angular.module('app', []).controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.user = [
                "userId": 1,
                "id": 1,
                "title": "DRF - Delegacia de Roubos e Furtos",
                "endereco": "Praca Maua, 5 - Centro",
                "tel":"2233-2701",
                "long":"-22.896893,0",
                "lat":"-43.181976"
                ];
});
```